# Как десериализовать json-строку в класс?

Tags: python, peewee

Использую `peewee` чтобы работать с БД. Как десериализовать `json`-строку в класс и залить его в БД?

```
class Operator(peewee.Model):
    id = peewee.PrimaryKeyField()
    
    site = peewee.CharField()
    
    changes = peewee.CharField()
    successCalls = peewee.IntegerField()
    callDuration = peewee.IntegerField()
    avgTimeSpent = peewee.IntegerField()
    totalTimeSpent = peewee.CharField()
    timeOutOfCalls = peewee.CharField()
    newOrders = peewee.IntegerField()
    todayApproved = peewee.IntegerField()
    approved = peewee.IntegerField()
    canceled = peewee.IntegerField()
    buyout = peewee.IntegerField()
    buyoutSum = peewee.IntegerField()
    approvedSum = peewee.IntegerField()
    approvedPrice = peewee.IntegerField()
    approve = peewee.IntegerField()
    clearApprove = peewee.IntegerField()
    buyoutProc = peewee.IntegerField()
    avgCheck = peewee.IntegerField()
    avgCheckBuyOut = peewee.IntegerField()
    upsellCoeff = peewee.IntegerField()
    operatorID = peewee.IntegerField()
    groupDateInterval = peewee.CharField()
    canceledProc = peewee.IntegerField()
    operator = peewee.CharField()

    class Meta:

        database = db
        db_table = 'operators'
```

Comment: чем "заливка" из json отличается от "заливки" из словаря, например?

Comment: Источник, предоставляющий json-строку, доверенный, или требуется проверять содержимое на корректность?

Comment: @andreymal корректный

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FkTkymTa

Comment: вот пример json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделал через приведение к типу Operator

```
req = requests.get(url)
jss = req.json()
for js in jss:
        o = Operator(**jss[js])
        o.save()
```

Comment: не то, чтоб это было "приведение к типу Operator", но - ок ;)